# How to display just the title of a cleveref reference to a tcolorbox?

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, tcolorbox, cleveref

While `\cref{vip:1-4}`---where `vip` refers to a `tcolorbox`---will typeset as `Alert 1-4 ∞ is not a number` and `\labelcref` will typeset as `1-4 ∞ is not a number`, occasionally I would like to go one step further and typeset only `∞ is not a number`.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{cleveref}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
    \newcounter{vip}% 
    \newtcolorbox%
    [%
    use counter= vip,
    number within=chapter,
    number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitlealert},%.
    crefname={Alert}{Alert},
    Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
    ]%
    {mportant}%
    [2][]%
    {%
    detach title,%
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,
    code={\gdef\mytitlealert{#2}},%
    title=ALERT \thetcbcounter,%
    #1,
    }%
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{mportant}[label={vip:1-4}]{$\infty$ is not a number}
\hspace{-3mm}and we cannot compute with $\infty$.
\end{mportant}
\chapter{Two}
We cannot input $\infty$ because \labelcref{vip:1-4}  (\Cpageref{vip:1-4})
\end{document}
```

and, occasionally, I would like not to have the reference number `1.1` at the beginning of the reference in:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use the `nameref=` option of `tcolorbox` (introduced on 2016/6/22 (the CHANGES file says 2016/7/14, however), version 3.94) and `\nameref` instead of `\labelcref` or `\cref` here since the `cleveref` feature is not necessary for this special title.

I used `nameref={#2}` since basically the title should be displayed and nothing else.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\newcounter{vip}% 
\usepackage{cleveref}%


\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= vip,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitlealert},%.
crefname={Alert}{Alert},
Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
]%
{mportant}%
[2][]%
{%
  detach title,%
  before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  nameref={#2},
  code={\gdef\mytitlealert{#2}},
  title={ALERT \thetcbcounter},%
  #1,
}%
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{mportant}[label={vip:1-4}]{$\infty$ is not a number}
\hspace{-3mm}and we cannot compute with $\infty$.
\end{mportant}
\chapter{Two}
We cannot input $\infty$ because \nameref{vip:1-4}  (\Cpageref{vip:1-4})
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just in case the `tcolorbox` version should be blatantly outdated, following `by-pass` solution by defining the `\@currentlabelname` (which is used by `\nameref`) in the `code={}` option can be applied -- of course, `\makeatletter...\makeatother` is necessary unless the definition of the box is written in a `.sty` or `.cls` file.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%
\usepackage{tcolorbox}%
\newcounter{vip}% 
\usepackage{cleveref}%


\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox%
[%
use counter= vip,
number within=chapter,
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitlealert},%.
crefname={Alert}{Alert},
Crefname={Alert}{Alerts},
]%
{mportant}%
[2][]%
{%
  detach title,%
  before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,
  code={\gdef\mytitlealert{#2}\edef\@currentlabelname{#2}},%
  title={ALERT \thetcbcounter},%
  #1,
}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{One}
\begin{mportant}[label={vip:1-4}]{$\infty$ is not a number}
\hspace{-3mm}and we cannot compute with $\infty$.
\end{mportant}
\chapter{Two}
We cannot input $\infty$ because \nameref{vip:1-4}  (\Cpageref{vip:1-4})
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice but my version is `2014/03/31` so I am first going to download the `2016/6/22` version but in a way so as to make sure I can go back if I break too much stuff. (I am using TeXLive-2013 under 10.6.8!) Will let you know.

Comment: @schremmer: Sigh! There's a 'harder' way to get the same result, but I can remember you wanted to update your system a long time ago ;-) What is `10.6.8.`? MacOS?

Comment: Thanks for your "just in case solution" but, and I can't really believe it, `tcolorbox 2017-07-05` did not break the magnum opus which is still under MacOS `10.6.8` =`Snow Leopard`. And of course your "easy" solution does it. Still can't believe it.