# Interrupting-modifying numbering of tcolorboxes

Tags: hyperref, tcolorbox

In the MWE I would like the numbering:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%================================================ Begin PREAMBLE 
\usepackage{relsize}        %Set the font size relative to the current font size    
\usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}%
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} %what does it do, why is it here?
 \usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc} 
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% 
\tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
    skins,%
    raster,%
    breakable,%
    xparse,%
        }%End load libraries for tcolorbox      
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]
\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
%============== Begin definition of EXAMPLE
\newcounter{XPL}%
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= XPL,
number within=chapter,%
crefname={\textsc{example}}{\textsc{examples}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Example}}{\textsc{Examples}},%
]%endForReferences
{EXAMPLE}%NameEnvironment
[2][]%WhateverThatIs
{%beginDescription
detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
left=-1mm,right=-1mm,
breakable,
enhanced,%
%grow to left by=5mm,
fontupper=\sffamily,
colback=white,
colframe=white,
fonttitle=\sffamily,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
coltitle=black,%
title={E\smaller{XAMPLE} \larger{\thetcbcounter}.\notblank{#2}{\hspace{2mm} #2}{}},%
#1,%
}%end Description
%============== End definition of EXAMPLE 
%============== Begin definition of DEMO
\newcounter{DMO}%[chapter]
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= DMO,
number within=chapter,%
list inside= DMO,%creates the list under tcblistof
%number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitlemod},%Makes for LONG titles in the references.
crefname={\textsc{demo}}{\textsc{demos}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Demo}}{\textsc{Demos}}%
]%endForReferences
{%beginNameEnvironment
DEMO%
}%endNameEnvironment
[2]%
[]%WhateverThatIs
{%begin Description OUTER tcbox
    breakable,
    enhanced,%
    detach title,
attach title to upper=~,%
lower separated=true,
bicolor,%
    boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=white,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=white,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=white,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
%   fonttitle=\small\sffamily,
fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,%
title={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter} \hspace{2mm} #2},%
#1%
}%end Description OUTER tcbox
%=========== End definition of DEMO
        %================= Begin definition of DEFINITION
    \newcounter{DFN}%[chapter] %To be entered in Control>ALL
    \newtcolorbox%
    [%beginForReferences
    use counter= DFN,
    number within=chapter,
    list inside= DFN,%creates the list under tcblistof
    %list type=definition,
    crefname={\textsc{definition}}{\textsc{definitions}},%
    Crefname={\textsc{Definition}}{\textsc{Definitions}},%
    ]%endForReferences
    {%beginNameEnvironment
    DEFINITION%
    }%EndNameEnvironment
    [2][]%Two brackets say to enter one label and one title?
    {%beginDescription
    detach title,%
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%
    breakable,%
    enhanced,%
    arc=0.2mm,%
    %fontupper=\sffamily,%NotSerifBecauseNotPartOfText
    colback= yellow!30,%
    colframe= yellow!35!black,%
    fonttitle=\bfseries,%
    coltitle=black,%
    %code={\gdef\mytitlealert{#2}},%Used to make for LONG titles in the references.
    title=D\smaller{EFINITION} \larger{\thetcbcounter\, #2},%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry={D\smaller{EFINITION}~\larger{\thetcbcounter ~ #2}},%the default format puts the label upfront
    #1,%Required for references.
    }%end Description
    %==================== End definition of DEFINITION
    %================ Begin definition of DEFINITIONrestated as per YASMAR and STURM
    \newcounter{DFNrst}
    \newtcolorbox%
    [%beginForReferences
    use counter=DFNrst,
    list inside= DFN,
    %number within=chapter,%
    crefname={definition (Restated)}{definitions (Restated)},%
    Crefname={Definition (Restated)}{Definitions (Restated)},%
    ]%endForReferences
    {%begin name environment
    DEFINITIONrestated%
    }%end name Environment
    [3][]%
    {%begin Format
    detach title,%This prevents the top from being the color of the frame
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},%This prevents the top from being the color of the frame
    %breakable,%WHY NOT?
    enhanced,%
    arc=0.2mm,%
    colback= yellow!30,%
    colframe= yellow!35!black,%
    fonttitle=\bfseries,%
    coltitle=black,%
    %begin TITLE
    title= D\smaller{EFINITION} ~\larger{\ref{#2}}~(Restated) \nameref{#2},%
    nameref={\getrefbykeydefault{#2}{name}{UNDEFINED REFERENCE}},%
    list entry= D\smaller{EFINITION}  ~\larger{\ref{#2}}~\nameref{#2} (Restated),%Order not the same as in THEOREMrestated
    label type={DFNrst},
    code={\renewcommand{\theDFNrst}{\getrefnumber{#2}}},
    #1%,
    %end TITLE
    }%end Format
    %============================== End definition of DEFINITIONrestated 

as per YASMAR and STURM
%================================================ End PREAMBLE 
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Something}\label{1-0-0}. 
    \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-1}]{~} 
    Text
    \end{EXAMPLE}
    \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-2}]{~} 
    Text
    \end{EXAMPLE}
    \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-3}]{~} 
    Text
    \end{EXAMPLE}
    \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-4}]{~} 
    Text
    \end{EXAMPLE}
    \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-5}]{~} 
    Text
    \end{EXAMPLE}
    
    References: \Cref{XPL:1-1}, \Cref{XPL:1-2}, \Cref{XPL:1-3}
    
    \bigskip
    \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-1}]{}
    Text
    \end{DEMO}
    \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-2}]{}
    Text
    \end{DEMO}
    \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-3}]{}
    Text
    \end{DEMO}
    \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-4}]{}
    Text
    \end{DEMO}
    \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-5}]{}
    Text
    \end{DEMO}

    References: \Cref{DMO:1-1}, \Cref{DMO:1-2a}, \Cref{DMO:1-2b}, \Cref{DMO:1-2c}, \Cref{DMO:1-3}
        %============================== begin DEFINITION
        % \INDEX[]{direct problems}     \INDEX[]{reverse problems}        \INDEX[]{given reference info}     \INDEX[]{given info of concern} 
        \begin{DEFINITION}[label={DFN:1-1}]{Title}
        
        This is yak, yak.
        \end{DEFINITION}
        %============================== end DEFINITION
        %============================== begin DEFINITION restated
        \begin{DEFINITIONrestated}[label={DFN:1-1a}]{DFN:1-1}{~}%
        
        This is now restated as YAK, YAK
        \end{DEFINITIONrestated}
        %================================== end DEFINITION restated

    \end{document}
```

Comment: What's the reason for `tcolorbox` when you essentially use no box?

Comment: You should see the Magnum Opus! I use them with a vengeance. I just thought of the continued example to replace  "In `\Cref{XPL:1-n}"` in a couple of places. As for the DEMOs, normally, I use a DEMO after each PROCEDURE but in a few places I need more than one DEMO after the PROCEDURE and I thought it would be better to keep the numbering of the DEMOS matched.with the numbering of the PROCEDURES. So, it;s not crucial but I sure hope you can fix it.

Comment: Hi, who are you directing this comment to? ("it;s not crucial but I sure hope you can fix it")

Comment: @Simon Dispa That one was, before there was any answer, for egreg who, by the way, later cleaned up my MWE a bit. But I did send you a comment which should appear below your answer.

Comment: I have added DEFINITION and DEFINITIONrestated as per YASMAR and STURM as a possible clue to the reference issue.

Comment: (1) You probably got the code between updates. Sorry for that. (2) The problem with the link you found is not coming from the code but from `hyperlink` Needs to be loaded as `\usepackage[hypertexnames=false, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}`. (3) I update my answer with your coloring recommendations and \newpage to test the links. More fun!

Comment: Just in case: I just updated the code. Only two tcolorbox for EXAMPLE. All the links work fine.

Comment: @SimonDispa Re. EXAMPLE, it was perfect but I will check the update later. Re. DEMOS To see the issues, in _your_ file, change the DEMOs' text to: Single DEMO for PROCEDURE 1.1, First DEMO for PROCEDURE 1.2, Second DEMO for PROCEDURE 1.2,Third DEMO for PROCEDURE 1.2, etc, Single DEMO for PROCEDURE 1.3. And I should have made it clear that I need links to refer to **_all_** DEMOs. I truly appreciate the work you put into it. My MWE was dismal but I really need the best possible reference system: the readers I am writing for need it absolutely. Else they drop out or, worse, try to memorize.

Comment: Thank for your feedback. To clarify: with links all DEMOS /PROCEDURES including the marked as  "with no label" in your MWE, as DEMO 1.2c for example?

Comment: @SimonDispa All DEMOs should have links because I learned that, while students will _read_ the PROCEDURE, they will _use_ the DEMO. Until now, all PROCEDUREs had _one_ DEMO but I recently ran into a situation where _one_ PROCEDURE, namely PROCEDURE 1.2, required _five_ DEMOs to cover all cases and then I realized this was now going to happen again and again. Hence this question. But, as I said, the MWE was terrible. So, thank YOU.

Comment: UPDATE #2 with PROCEDURE, all linked. Disregard previous code.

Comment: @SimonDispa Almost perfect !!! If you look below, you will see, e.g. `PROCEDURE 1.2.a`. Would it be possible to get rid of the dot between the `2` and the `a` and get `PROCEDURE 1.2a` ?

Comment: Updated to remove the dot. Changed the figure and the code (only two lines changed). How close am I from perfect? :-) I do not mind having your feedback to refine the code. On the contrary.

Comment: @SimonDispa Works fine in the text but not in the `\tcblistof[\chapter]{DMO}{List of Demos}`. See pp. 91, 92 and 107 of [link](http://freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW-v1.1/TempChap1.pdf)

Comment: Updated to get the List of Procedures. New files: main code and PROCEDURE_def.. Figure added to the answer. To produce the list use `\tcblistof[\chapter]{PROC}{List of  Procedures}` .

Comment: @SimonDispa Sorry to be late. Got the list of Procedures but couldn't get rid of the front reference as in `1.1 PROCEDURE 1.1` instead of `PROCEDURE 1.1` Otherwise, everything seems OK.

Comment: @SimonDispa Not quite: if you move `PROCEDURE 1-4`, `PROCEDURE 1-5`, `PROCEDURE 1-6a`, `PROCEDURE 1-6b`, ... `PROCEDURE 1-7`, to Chapter 2, you will see that the numbering is wrong:  ... `PROCEDURE 1-3`, `PROCEDURE 2-4`, `PROCEDURE 2-5`, `PROCEDURE 2-6a`, `PROCEDURE 2-6b`,... `PROCEDURE 2-7`, instead of ... `PROCEDURE 1-3`, `PROCEDURE 2-1`, `PROCEDURE 2-2`, `PROCEDURE 2-3a`, `PROCEDURE 2-3b`, ... `PROCEDURE 2-4`. In other words, the _procedure_ number is not reset with the new chapter.

Comment: Added a new update. Changes in main and PROCEDURES_def. Added more examples for chapter 2. Please download all the files and test again. Thank you for your patience and feedback.

Comment: @SimonDispa You seem to have solved the second issue (about restarting the _procedure number_ when there is a _new chapter number_) but, according to what I see below, you forgot about the first issue, which is that, in the `List of Procedures`  it should be  `PROCEDURE 1.1`  instead of `1.1 PROCEDURE 1.1`. (In other words,`1.1` should appear _only once_, after `Procedure`)

Comment: Sorry. I was using the default and forgot. It is corrected now. Use the new `PROCEDURE_def`.

Comment: @SimonDispa Everything is now fine. This [link](http://www.freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW-v1.1/CARW_2021-05-14.pdf) will show you that all the work you did was for a good, open source, cause. Thanks for these readers.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.

Comment: @SimonDispa Sorry to bother you again but, when I add DEMOS to the document, the numbering of the DEMOS is strangely wrong. See [link](http://freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW-v1.1/Strange%20Malfunctioning.zip)  for a complete compilable example that includes yours. Details on the first page of `Document.pdf`

Comment: I will look the issue. We never tried before an intertwined of demos an procedures. Try to see if there are more configurations to test. Otherwise the development will never end.

Comment: @SimonDispa I will try to think of other configurations but I think that's it. But sorry for the bother anyway.

Comment: @SimonDispa Found one thing I had forgotten. See the above link which I updated.

Comment: Please test this new delivery [Fixes](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16A4CZlgpqkw6k3k5hq0DtLtcpZ54M74h/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SimonDispa On page 6, it shouldn't be `PROCEDURE 1.10a` and `PROCEDURE 1.10b` but `PROCEDURE 1.10` and the new tcbox `PROCEDURErestated 1.10` which Yasmar -Sturm defined to automatically get its number from `PROCEDURE 1.10`. _See my link_. And then, after `PROCEDURE 1.10`, there should be `DEMO 1.10a`, `DEMO 1.10b`, `DEMO 1.10c` and after `PROCEDURErestated 1.10` there should be the new tcbox `DEMOrestated 1.10a`, `DEMOrestated 1.10b`, `DEMOrestated 1.10c` which automatically get their numbers from `DEMO 1.10a`, `DEMO 1.10b`, `DEMO 1.10c`.

Comment: @SimonDispa See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348263/how-to-restate-a-theorem-keeping-the-same-number and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404553/how-to-label-a-restated-theorem

Comment: To get `PROCEDURE 1.10` change `\begin{PROCEDUREsub}[label={PROC:1-10}]` to `\begin{PROCEDURE}[label={PROC:1-10}]`. DEMOS 1.10a to c are fine after. I do not understand the restarted. You want to reuse a previous number?

Comment: @SimonDispa I will check tomorrow. Re "the restated" (not "the restarted") here is how Sturm put it in `https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348263/how-to-restate-a-theorem-keeping-the-same-number': "If I understand the problem correctly, you want to restate der theorem number, but put a modified text into the restated theorem (as in the yasmar answer)."

Comment: I got it. This might be a new requirement You want to be able to have a PROCEDURE or DEMO with the same number of a former one with different content. And links to either of them? It seems **you already have a solution** but in   your last  zip you did not included the code used for  DEMOrestated so I changed ro DEMOsub etc. Sorry for the confusion. Lets start again with the full code you are using and test cases.

Comment: @SimonDispa Absolutely correct. **I** am sorry for the confusion. Glad Sturm bailed me out. I want to double check my "solution" and upload a new zip _at the same link_. But I need a few hours and I will let you know when. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @SimonDispa I have "restated" (!!!) your FIXED here: [link](http://freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW-v1.1/RestatedFIXED.zip)

Comment: Clear as crystal.

Comment: @schremmer New delivery with restated DEMOsub and PROCEDUREDsub. Please keep me posted of the testing results.
[RestatedSUB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q7bs9_iDZchRd4MkKw5CI_Vc-6yq_aUY/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SimonDispa Getting there: Demo 2.1a, 2.1b, 2.1c now correctly appear as Demo 1.10a Restated, Demo 1.10b Restated, Demo 1.10c Restated between Procedure 1.10 Restated and Procedure 1.11 Restated. You then restated Procedure 1.8a which appears correctly as Procedure 1.8a Restated but only AFTER Demo 1.11 Restated. Same for Demo 1.8a Restated, Procedure 1.8b Restated. And then there is a Procedure 1.8c Restated but there is NO Procedure 1.8c. From the _title_, it seems to be another restatement of Procedure 1.10 but from the _subtitle_ it seems to be another restatement of Procedure 1.8b

Comment: (1) The `restated` takes 3 parameters: (#1) Its own label, (#2) a label of the "original" and (#3) title of the "original". But #2 and #3 are in fact arbitrary and using for printing the output as `(Restated)` and making the links. There is **no check** that the "original" actually exists. It is just a rubber stamp with the content you choose. (Procedure 1.8c is there, page 5. see the list)

(2) `DEMO` and `PROCEDURE` are  independent chains. There are no sync between their numbers, they increase independently. Only the `sub`(s) take their number from their parent until `end`.

Comment: (3) In summary it is up to the user to insert the proper contents in the proper order. In the final examples I did it carelessly (not on purpose) restating PROC 1.8a to c after PROC 1.11, and using wrong titles,  but serves to illustrate the point.

Comment: @SimonDispa Thanks for the info. In other words, what I had forgotten is that "originals" are numbered by LaTeX (according to where they are in the chapter) but that the numbering of "Restateds" depends only on the "original" and NOT on where they are. Shame on me. So, EVERYTHING WORKS. And, THANKS again for this epic amount of work. The Magnum Opus will never be the same.

Comment: It was a pleasure and a privilege to participate in real work instead of misleading  MWEs. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @SimonDispa Your code is still rock solid but I ran into a glitch when I moved it to the working structure I am using for the Magnum Opus. I can of course abandon my working structure but I am wondering if you might be willing to take a look at [glitch](http://freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW-v1.1/GlitchInRestatedSUB.zip).

Comment: @schremmer I will do my best.

Comment: Please see [CorrectedGlitch](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GmO5nwlqwzRfxadqS8mJVSZAV8FUvAU5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @SimonDispa Not only did your best work (of course) but in two hours? I will move it to the [magnum opus](http://freemathtexts.org/Calculus/Schremmer_CARW-v1.1/ALL.pdf) in a couple of days and watch out better for _my_ mistakes. Thanks again.

Comment: @schremmer Serendipity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE** after several follow-up comments.

To get some automation, I defined several new `tcolorboxes`.

(1) For EXAMPLE mode: the normal `tcolorbox` and a second, used with the `(Continuation)`, which keeps the same number and adds the word.

(2) For PROCEDURE mode: the normal box, the middle tcolorboxes with an alpha counter added, and the last one of this mode to reset the counters.

(3) The package `hyperref` has to be loaded with the option `hypertexnames=false` to avoid the jumping to wrong places. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3197/161015

I run several tests:

(1) Copy and pasted several boxes in the middle in both modes to test the automatisms.

(2) Started a new chapter to verify the first number and correct initialization.

(3) Checked all links.

To unclutter up the code, I put the EXAMPLE definitions and the DEMOS definitions in separate files, and also  for the examples of use of EXAMPLE and PROCEDURE.

[image: a]

[image: c]

[image: x1]

[image: x3]

This the main code (updated)

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
%================================================ Begin PREAMBLE 
%   

%%% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\chapter}{% reset counters & add some space in list
\setcounter{PROCstore}{0}%
\setcounter{DMOstore}{0}%
\setcounter{DMOm}{0}%
\setcounter{subDMOm}{0}%
\setcounter{PROCm}{0}%
\setcounter{subPROCm}{0}%
\addtocontents{PROC}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}%
\addtocontents{DMO}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}%
{}{}
%% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}          
\definecolor{LightGray}{gray}{0.990}%gray is pre-defined; 1 is white
\definecolor{DarkGray}{gray}{0.85}%gray is pre-defined; 1 is white
\colorlet{LightBlue}{blue!3!white}%d color for the rest
\colorlet{DarkBlue}{blue!20!white}%second color for the rest
\newcommand{\INDEX}[2][]{\phantomsection%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\index{#2}\label{ind:#2}%
\else\index{#2}\label{ind:#1}\fi%
}%
\newcommand{\DEX}[2][]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\hyperref[ind:#2]{#2}%
% (\Cpageref{ind:#2})%
\else\hyperref[ind:#1]{#2}%
%(\Cpageref{ind:#1})%
\fi%
}%
\usepackage{relsize}        %Set the font size relative to the current font size    
\usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}%
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} %what does it do, why is it here?
\usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc}  
\usepackage{tcolorbox}% 
\tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
    skins,%
    raster,%
    breakable,%
    xparse,%
}%End load libraries for tcolorbox   

\usepackage[hypertexnames=false, hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
    
\input{EXAMPLE_def} % EXAMPLE tcolorboxes   

\input{PROCEDURE_def} % PROCEDURE tcolorboxes needs patch to reset chapter number 

\input{DEMO_def} % DEMO tcolorboxes  needs patch to reset chapter number

%================================================ End PREAMBLE 
\begin{document}    
  
\input{TestingText}

\end{document}
```

This the file `EXAMPLE_def.tex`

```
%%%%%% file EXAMPLE_def starts G2-3 <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

%============== Begin definition of EXAMPLE
\newcounter{XPL}%
\newcounter{XPLm}% just in case
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= XPL,
number within=chapter,%
crefname={\textsc{example}}{\textsc{examples}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Example}}{\textsc{Examples}},%
]%endForReferences
{EXAMPLE}%NameEnvironment
[2][]%WhateverThatIs
{%beginDescription
    detach title,
    before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
    left=-1mm,right=-1mm,
    breakable,
    enhanced,%
    %grow to left by=5mm,
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    colback=white,
    colframe=cyan,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,%
        top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    title={E\smaller{XAMPLE} \larger{\theXPL}.\notblank{#2}{\hspace{2mm} #2}{}},%
    #1,%
}%end Description
%============== End definition of EXAMPLE 

%============== Begin definition of EXAMPLEcont
\newtcolorbox%
[%beginForReferences
use counter= XPL,
number within=chapter,%
crefname={\textsc{example}}{\textsc{examples}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Example}}{\textsc{Examples}},%
]%endForReferences
{EXAMPLEcont}%NameEnvironment
[2][]%WhateverThatIs
{%beginDescription
    detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
    before title=   \addtocounter{XPL}{-1}\addtocounter{XPLm}{1}, % count med in case if needed
    left=-1mm,right=-1mm,
    breakable,
    enhanced,%
    %grow to left by=5mm,
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    colback=white,
    colframe=yellow,
    fonttitle=\sffamily,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    coltitle=black,%
        top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    title={E\smaller{XAMPLE} \larger{\theXPL}.\notblank{#2}{\hspace{2mm}(Continued) #2}{}},%
    #1,%
}%end Description
%============== End definition of EXAMPLEcont

%%%%%% file EXAMPLE_def ends <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

This is the file  file `PROCEDURE_def.tex` (updated on request)

```
    %%%%%% file PROCEDURE_def starts G4 1 needs patch <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\newcounter{PROC}%[chapter] %   \renewcommand{\thePROC}{\number\numexpr\value{PROC}+1\relax}% Display PROC+1
\newcounter{PROCm}%
\newcounter{PROCstore}%
\newcounter{subPROCm}% a b c .
\newcounter{subPROCpass}%% on off

%============== Begin definition of PROCEDURE
\newtcolorbox[%
auto counter, 
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{PROC}},
number within=chapter,%
list inside= PROC,%creates the list under tcblistof.
crefname={\textsc{procedure}}{\textsc{procedures}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Procedure}}{\textsc{Procedures}}%  
]
{PROCEDURE}[2][]{%
    code=%  
    \setcounter{PROC}{\value{PROCstore}}%   
    \setcounter{subPROCpass}{0}%     
    \addtocounter{PROC}{1}  ,
    after title=%   
    \setcounter{PROCstore}{\value{PROC}}, 
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper=~,%
    lower separated=true,
    bicolor,%
    %   boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=DarkBlue,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=DarkBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=LightBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=5pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry={\textbf{P\smaller{ROCEDURE}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    title={\textbf{P\smaller{ROCEDURE}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    #1%
}
%=========== End definition of PROCEDURE


%============== Begin definition of PROCEDUREsub   
\newtcolorbox[%
%use counter= PROC,
auto counter, 
number within=chapter, 
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{PROCm}\noexpand\alph{subPROCm}},%
list inside= PROC,%creates the list under tcblistof.
crefname={\textsc{procedure}}{\textsc{procedures}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Procedure}}{\textsc{Procedures}},%    
]
{PROCEDUREsub}[2][]{%
    code=%
    \setcounter{PROCm}{\value{PROCstore}}%   
    \addtocounter{PROCm}{1}% 
    \addtocounter{subPROCm}{1},
    after title=%
    \addtocounter{\tcbcounter}{1} , 
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper=~,%
    lower separated=true,
    bicolor,%
%   boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=DarkBlue,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=DarkBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=LightBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=5pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry= {\textbf{P\smaller{ROCEDURE}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    title= {\textbf{P\smaller{ROCEDURE}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    #1%
}   
%=========== End definition of PROCEDURE sub

%============== Begin definition of PROCEDUREend
\newtcolorbox[%
%%use counter= PROCm,
auto counter, 
number within=chapter, 
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{PROCm}\noexpand\alph{subPROCm}},%
list inside= PROC,%creates the list under tcblistof.
crefname={\textsc{procedure}}{\textsc{procedures}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Procedure}}{\textsc{Procedures}},%    
]
{PROCEDUREend}[2][]{%
    code=%
    \setcounter{PROCm}{\value{PROCstore}}%   
    \addtocounter{PROCm}{1}% 
    \addtocounter{subPROCm}{1}% 
    \setcounter{subPROCpass}{1} ,
    after title=%
    \setcounter{PROCstore}{\value{PROCm}}% 
        \setcounter{subPROCm}{0}, 
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper=~,%
    lower separated=true,
    bicolor,%
    %   boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=DarkBlue,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=DarkBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=LightBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=5pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry={\textbf{P\smaller{ROCEDURE}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    title={\textbf{P\smaller{ROCEDURE}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    #1%
}   
    %=========== End definition of PROCEDUREend
    
%%%%%% file PROCEDURE_def ends <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

This the file DEMO_def

```
%%%%%% file DEMO_def starts G4 1 needs patch <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


\newcounter{DMO}%[chapter] %   \renewcommand{\theDMO}{\number\numexpr\value{DMO}+1\relax}% Display DMO+1
\newcounter{DMOm}%
\newcounter{DMOstore}%
\newcounter{subDMOm}% a b c 
\newcounter{subDMOpass}%% on off

%============== Begin definition of DEMO
\newtcolorbox[%
auto counter, 
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{DMO}},
number within=chapter,%
list inside= DMO,%creates the list under tcblistof.
crefname={\textsc{demo}}{\textsc{demos}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Demo}}{\textsc{Demos}}%
]
{DEMO}[2][]{%
    code=%  
    \setcounter{DMO}{\value{DMOstore}}% 
        \setcounter{subDMOpass}{0}%     
    \addtocounter{DMO}{1},
    after title=%   
    \setcounter{DMOstore}{\value{DMO}}, 
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper=~,%
    lower separated=true,
    bicolor,%
    %   boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=DarkBlue,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=DarkBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=LightBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=5pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    title={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    #1%
}
%=========== End definition of DEMO


%============== Begin definition of DEMO sub   
\newtcolorbox[%
%use counter= DMO,
auto counter, 
number within=chapter, 
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{DMOm}\noexpand\alph{subDMOm}},%
list inside= DMO,%creates the list under tcblistof.
crefname={\textsc{demo}}{\textsc{demos}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Demo}}{\textsc{Demos}}% 
]
{DEMOsub}[2][]{%
    code=%
    \setcounter{DMOm}{\value{DMOstore}}%   
    \addtocounter{DMOm}{1}% 
    \addtocounter{subDMOm}{1},
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper=~,%
    lower separated=true,
    bicolor,%
%   boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=DarkBlue,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=DarkBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=LightBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=5pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    title={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    #1%
}
%=========== End definition of DEMO sub

%============== Begin definition of DEMO end
\newtcolorbox[%
%%use counter= DMOm,
auto counter, 
number within=chapter, 
number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{DMOm}\noexpand\alph{subDMOm}},%
list inside= DMO,%creates the list under tcblistof.
crefname={\textsc{demo}}{\textsc{demos}},%
Crefname={\textsc{Demo}}{\textsc{Demos}}%  
]
{DEMOend}[2][]{%
    code=%
    \setcounter{DMOm}{\value{DMOstore}}%   
    \addtocounter{DMOm}{1}% 
    \addtocounter{subDMOm}{1}% 
    \setcounter{subDMOpass}{1},
    after title=%
    \setcounter{DMOstore}{\value{DMOm}}% 
        \setcounter{subDMOm}{0}%  
        \setcounter{DMOm}{0}, 
    enhanced,
    breakable,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper=~,%
    lower separated=true,
    bicolor,%
    %   boxrule=1mm,%
    colframe=DarkBlue,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
    colback=DarkBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    colbacklower=LightBlue,%This is the background color below the title.
    top=0pt,
    bottom=0pt,
    boxsep=5pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
    outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
    fontupper=\sffamily,
    fontlower=\sffamily,
    coltitle=black,%
    nameref={#2},%
    list entry={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    title={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}\hspace{2mm} #2},%
    #1%
}   
    %=========== End definition of DEMOend
    
%%%%%% file DEMO_def ends <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

Comment: 1. In my preamble, I replaced my definition of EXAMPLE by your definition of EXAMPLE, EXAMPLEcont and EXAMPLEend in ref2 and it compiles. But there is something wrong with the references. 2. To trace, I changed  colback=white to cyan in your EXAMPLE, to yellow in your EXAMPLEcont, and to green in your EXAMPLEend. (This showed that you forgot to use EXAMPLEend for the last EXAMPLE 1.2) The problem is that Cref{XPL:1-3} refers to the first EXAMPLE (Continued).

Comment: @schremmer Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Will look it up tomorrow. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Except for the references to DEMOs, you can adjust manually adjust counters and titles

```
 \documentclass[11pt]{book}
  %================================================ Begin PREAMBLE 
  \usepackage{relsize}        %Set the font size relative to the current font size    
  \usepackage[neveradjust]{paralist}%
  \usepackage{titlesec} 
  \usepackage{etoolbox} %what does it do, why is it here?
   \usepackage[dotinlabels]{titletoc} 
  \usepackage{tcolorbox}% 
  \tcbuselibrary{%Begin load libraries for tcolorbox  
      skins,%
      raster,%
      breakable,%
      xparse,%
          }%End load libraries for tcolorbox      
  \usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}%[pdfborder={0 0 0}]
  \usepackage{cleveref}% should be the last package
  %============== Begin definition of EXAMPLE
  \newcounter{XPL}%
  \newtcolorbox%
  [%beginForReferences
  use counter= XPL,
  number within=chapter,%
  crefname={\textsc{example}}{\textsc{examples}},%
  Crefname={\textsc{Example}}{\textsc{Examples}},%
  ]%endForReferences
  {EXAMPLE}%NameEnvironment
  [2][]%WhateverThatIs
  {%beginDescription
  detach title,before upper={\tcbtitle\quad},
  left=-1mm,right=-1mm,
  breakable,
  enhanced,%
  %grow to left by=5mm,
  fontupper=\sffamily,
  colback=white,
  colframe=white,
  fonttitle=\sffamily,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
  coltitle=black,%
  title={E\smaller{XAMPLE} \larger{\thetcbcounter}.\notblank{#2}{\ #2}{}},%
  #1,%
  }%end Description
  %============== End definition of EXAMPLE 
  %============== Begin definition of DEMO
  \newcounter{DMO}%[chapter]
  \newtcolorbox%
  [%beginForReferences
  use counter= DMO,
  number within=chapter,%
  list inside= DMO,%creates the list under tcblistof
  %number freestyle={\noexpand\thechapter.\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}~\noexpand\mytitlemod},%Makes for LONG titles in the references.
  crefname={\textsc{demo}}{\textsc{demos}},%
  Crefname={\textsc{Demo}}{\textsc{Demos}}%
  ]%endForReferences
  {%beginNameEnvironment
  DEMO%
  }%endNameEnvironment
  [2]%
  []%WhateverThatIs
  {%begin Description OUTER tcbox
      breakable,
      enhanced,%
      detach title,
  attach title to upper=~,%
  lower separated=true,
  bicolor,%
      boxrule=1mm,%
      colframe=white,%controls both the background color for the top and the frame of the bottom
      colback=white,%This is the background color below the title.
      colbacklower=white,%This is the background color below the title.
      top=0pt,
      bottom=0pt,
      boxsep=0pt,% Sets a common padding between text and frame of box. Added to left, right, top, bottom, and middle.
      outer arc=2mm,%when line is thick. Else, can just use arc.
      fontupper=\sffamily,
      fontlower=\sffamily,
  %   fonttitle=\small\sffamily,
  fonttitle=\bfseries,
      coltitle=black,%
  title={\textbf{D\smaller{EMO}}\hspace{1.5mm}\textbf{\thetcbcounter}#2},%
  #1%
  }%end Description OUTER tcbox
  %=========== End definition of DEMO
  %================================================ End PREAMBLE 
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{Something}\label{1-0-0}. 
  \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-1}]{~} 
  To remain \textsc{Example} 1.1 with label XPL:1-1
  \end{EXAMPLE}
  \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-2}]{~} 
  To remain \textsc{Example} 1.2 with label XPL:1-2
  \end{EXAMPLE}
  \addtocounter{XPL}{-1}
  \begin{EXAMPLE}[]{(Continued)} 
  To become \textsc{Example} 1.2 (Continued) with no label
  \end{EXAMPLE}
  \begin{EXAMPLE}[code={\addtocounter{XPL}{-1}}]{(Continued)} 
  To become \textsc{Example} 1.2 (Continued) with no label
  \end{EXAMPLE}
  \begin{EXAMPLE}[label={XPL:1-3}]{~} 
  To be \textsc{Example} 1.3 with label XPL:1-3
  \end{EXAMPLE}

  References: \Cref{XPL:1-1}, \Cref{XPL:1-2}, \Cref{XPL:1-3}

  \bigskip
  \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-1}]{}
  To remain DEMO 1.1 with label DMO:1-1
  \end{DEMO}
  \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-2a}]{a}
  To become DEMO 1.2a with label DMO:1-2a
  \end{DEMO}
  \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-2b}, code={\addtocounter{DMO}{-1}}]{b}
  To become DEMO 1.2b with label DMO:1-2b
  \end{DEMO}
  \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-2c}, code={\addtocounter{DMO}{-1}}]{c}
  To become DEMO 1.2c with label DMO:1-2c
  \end{DEMO}
  \begin{DEMO}[label={DMO:1-3}]{ test}
  To be DEMO 1.3 with label DMO:1.3
  \end{DEMO}

  References: \Cref{DMO:1-1}, \Cref{DMO:1-2a}, \Cref{DMO:1-2b}, \Cref{DMO:1-2c}, \Cref{DMO:1-3}

  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your answer for EXAMPLE (Continued) works perfectly. With DEMO, as you warned, there is trouble with references. 1. I cannot refer with Cref to DEMO 1.2a. 1.2b and 1.2c.  2. While DEMO 1.2a, 1.2b, 1.2c are all listedcorrectly in the Appendix they too all refer to Demo 2a. Because of the kind of reader I am writing for, I really cannot do that. (By the way, even though Demos do have titles, a, b, c can be included in the title with only a bit of tinkering.)